# How to differentiate a file like object from a file path like object

Tags: python, python-3.x

### Summary:

There is a variety of function for which it would be very useful to be able to pass in two kinds of objects: an object that represents a path (usually a string), and an object that represents a stream of some sort (often something derived from `IOBase`, but not always). How can this variety of function differentiate between these two kinds of objects so they can be handled appropriately?

---

Say I have a function intended to write a file from some kind of object file generator method:

```
spiff = MySpiffy()

def spiffy_file_makerA(spiffy_obj, file):
    file_str = '\n'.join(spiffy_obj.gen_file()) 
    file.write(file_str)

with open('spiff.out', 'x') as f:
    spiffy_file_makerA(spiff, f)
    ...do other stuff with f...
```

This works. Yay. But I'd prefer to not have to worry about opening the file first or passing streams around, at least sometimes... so I refactor with the ability to take a file path like object instead of a file like object, and a `return` statement:

```
def spiffy_file_makerB(spiffy_obj, file, mode):
    file_str = '\n'.join(spiffy_obj.gen_file()) 
    file = open(file, mode)
    file.write(file_str)
    return file

with spiffy_file_makerB(spiff, 'file.out', 'x') as f:
    ...do other stuff with f...
```

But now I get the idea that it would be useful to have a third function that combines the other two versions depending on whether `file` is file like, or file path like, but returns the f destination file like object to a context manager. So that I can write code like this:

```
with  spiffy_file_makerAB(spiffy_obj, file_path_like, mode = 'x') as f:
    ...do other stuff with f...
```

...but also like this:

```
file_like_obj = get_some_socket_or_stream()

with spiffy_file_makerAB(spiffy_obj, file_like_obj, mode = 'x'):
    ...do other stuff with file_like_obj...
    # file_like_obj stream closes when context manager exits 
    # unless `closefd=False`
```

Note that this will require something a bit different than the simplified versions provided above.

Try as a I might, I haven't been able to find an obvious way to do this, and the ways I have found seem pretty contrived and just a potential for problems later. For example:

```
def spiffy_file_makerAB(spiffy_obj, file, mode, *, closefd=True):
    try: 
        # file-like (use the file descriptor to open)
        result_f = open(file.fileno(), mode, closefd=closefd)
    except TypeError: 
        # file-path-like
        result_f = open(file, mode)
    finally: 
        file_str = '\n'.join(spiffy_obj.gen_file()) 
        result_f.write(file_str)
        return result_f
```

Are there any suggestions for a better way? Am I way off base and need to be handling this completely differently?

Comment: I once found a [<blog entry>](https://leemendelowitz.github.io/blog/decorating-python-file-functions.html) about this issue. This can be done with a decorator.

Comment: FWIW I think the exception route is the right way to go. As soon as you start checking types, you hurt portability (py 2 but maybe you don't care) and also invite bugs in future python versions.

Comment: It's very common for open/load methods in Python modules to detect the type of the object passed, beit filename or file object. Perhaps have a look at the code behind PIL's image open: http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.open

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For my money, and this is an opinionated answer, checking for the attributes of the file-like object for the operations you will need is **a** pythonic way to determine an object’s type because that is the nature of pythonic [duck tests/duck-typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing):

> Duck typing is heavily used in Python, with the canonical example being file-like classes (for example, `cStringIO` allows a Python string to be treated as a file).

[Or from the python docs’ definition of duck-typing](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-duck-typing)

> A programming style which does not look at an object’s type to determine if it has the right interface; instead, the method or attribute is simply called or used (“*If it looks like a duck and quacks like a duck, it must be a duck.*”) By emphasizing interfaces rather than specific types, well-designed code improves its flexibility by allowing polymorphic substitution. Duck-typing avoids tests using `type()` or `isinstance()`. (Note, however, that duck-typing can be complemented with abstract base classes.) Instead, it typically employs `hasattr()` tests or EAFP programming.

If you feel very strongly that there is some very good reason that just checking the interface for suitability isn't enough, you can just reverse the test and test for `basestring` or `str` to test whether the provided object is path-like.  The test will be different depending on your version of python.

```
is_file_like = not isinstance(fp, basestring) # python 2
is_file_like = not isinstance(fp, str) # python 3
```

In any case, for your context manager, I would go ahead and make a full-blown object like the below in order to wrap the functionality that you were looking for.

```
class SpiffyContextGuard(object):
    def __init__(self, spiffy_obj, file, mode, closefd=True):
        self.spiffy_obj = spiffy_obj
        is_file_like = all(hasattr(attr) for attr in ('seek', 'close', 'read', 'write'))
        self.fp = file if is_file_like else open(file, mode)
        self.closefd = closefd

    def __enter__(self):
        return self.fp

    def __exit__(self, type_, value, traceback):
        generated = '\n'.join(self.spiffy_obj.gen_file())
        self.fp.write(generated)
        if self.closefd:
            self.fp.__exit__()
```

And then use it like this:

```
with SpiffyContextGuard(obj, 'hamlet.txt', 'w', True) as f:
    f.write('Oh that this too too sullied flesh\n')

fp = open('hamlet.txt', 'a')
with SpiffyContextGuard(obj, fp, 'a', False) as f:
    f.write('Would melt, thaw, resolve itself into a dew\n')

with SpiffyContextGuard(obj, fp, 'a', True) as f:
    f.write('Or that the everlasting had not fixed his canon\n')
```

If you wanted to use try/catch semantics to check for type suitability, you could also wrap the file operations you wanted to expose on your context guard:

```
class SpiffyContextGuard(object):
    def __init__(self, spiffy_obj, file, mode, closefd=True):
        self.spiffy_obj = spiffy_obj
        self.fp = self.file_or_path = file 
        self.mode = mode
        self.closefd = closefd

    def seek(self, offset, *args):
        try:
            self.fp.seek(offset, *args)
        except AttributeError:
            self.fp = open(self.file_or_path, mode)
            self.fp.seek(offset, *args)

    # define wrappers for write, read, etc., as well

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type_, value, traceback):
        generated = '\n'.join(self.spiffy_obj.gen_file())
        self.write(generated)
        if self.closefd:
            self.fp.__exit__()
```

Comment: This answer is a quick education in the advantages of duck typing, it reveals a pattern that's useful not just to solve similar problems in Python but also in other languages, and what a good quote to choose too.

Comment: Getting answers like this is why I love the bounty system.

Comment: This is no longer best practice; you'll need to check for `PathLike` _and_ `str` because there's now an actual `PathLike` thing. What I've described also isn't best practice, but it's the smallest modification required to your code to make it work with path-like objects (if I'm not making a stupid mistake).

Comment: Actually, best practice is `try: fp = os.fspath(fp) except TypeError:`.

Answer (score 4):

my suggestion is to pass [`pathlib.Path` objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) around. you can simply [`.write_bytes(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.write_bytes) or  [`.write_text(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.write_text) to these objects.

other that that you'd have to check the type of your `file` variable (this is how polymorphism can be done in python):

```
from io import IOBase

def some_function(file)
    if isinstance(file, IOBase):
        file.write(...)
    else:
        with open(file, 'w') as file_handler:
            file_handler.write(...)
```

(i hope [`io.IOBase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase) is the most basic class to check against...). and you would have to catch possible exceptions around all that.

Comment: It's surprising to me that there isn't a more obvious check out there- like a stream abstract baseclass (I know `io.IOBase` is an ABC but I don't think it implements a `__subclasshook__`), or something. Is io.IOBase really going to catch any kind of stream?

Comment: unfortunately [PEP 3116](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3116/) does not mention a `__subclasshook__` (neither does the doc; did not look at the source). you might define an own abstract base class with  a `__subclasshook__` that checks for a `write()` method. apart from that `IOBase` should be the parent of any stream. (can't speak for 3rd party libraries, of course...)

Comment: I've been exploring the `pathlib` module a bit more today, and it is very powerful. I am leaning toward abandoning the old/usual way of resolving strings into file streams altogether (using `open` and `os.path`, etc etc). The only potential problem with this I see is that a function that expects to be seeing `Path` objects is going to throw around exceptions when passed strings representing `Path`s. I suppose I could just wrap the (potential) strings in `Path`s each time a function getting something path-like is called, but that seems wrong since they might be a `Path` subclass. Thoughts?

Comment: @RickTeachey i have never subclassed `Path`, i usually call `Path(str(obj))` so if the subclass has a reasonable `__str__` method you should be fine... i have cleaned up my codebase so i really can pass `Path` objects and do not have to cast.

Comment: I suppose I actually meant, instead of subclassing `Path`, that it could be a different object implementing the path-like protocol. So assuming it can be passed to `Path` without consequence seems hazardous. However, `Path(str(obj))` seems like an OK way around the problem.

Comment: `Path(os.fspath(obj))` is better.

Answer (score 3):

Probably not the answer you're looking for, but from a taste point of view I think it's better to have functions that only do one thing. Reasoning about them is easier this way.

I'd just have two functions: `spiffy_file_makerA(spiffy_obj, file)`, which handles your first case, and a convenience function that wraps `spiffy_file_makerA` and creates a file for you.

Comment: I originally didn't like this answer, but after thinking about it a bit more, it's a worthwhile point of view. I have added another answer expanding on this idea.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach to this problem, inspired by this talk from [Raymond Hettinger at PyCon 2013](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HTLu2DFOdTg), would be to keep the two functions separate as suggested by a couple of the other answers, but to bring the functions together into a class with a number of alternative options for outputting the object.

Continuing with the example I started with, it might look something like this:

```
class SpiffyFile(object):
    def __init__(self, spiffy_obj, file_path = None, *, mode = 'w'):
        self.spiffy = spiffy_obj
        self.file_path = file_path
        self.mode = mode
    def to_str(self):
        return '\n'.join(self.spiffy.gen_file())
    def to_stream(self, fstream):
        fstream.write(self.to_str())
    def __enter__(self):
        try:
            # do not override an existing stream
            self.fstream
        except AttributeError:
            # convert self.file_path to str to allow for pathlib.Path objects
            self.fstream = open(str(self.file_path), mode = self.mode)
        return self
    def __exit__(self, exc_t, exc_v, tb):
        self.fstream.close()
        del self.fstream
    def to_file(self, file_path = None, mode = None):
        if mode is None:
            mode = self.mode
        try:
            fstream = self.fstream
        except AttributeError:
            if file_path is None:
                file_path = self.file_path
            # convert file_path to str to allow for pathlib.Path objects
            with open(str(file_path), mode = mode) as fstream:
                self.to_stream(fstream)
        else:
            if mode != fstream.mode:
                raise IOError('Ambiguous stream output mode: \
                           provided mode and fstream.mode conflict')
            if file_path is not None:
                raise IOError('Ambiguous output destination: \
                           a file_path was provided with an already active file stream.')
            self.to_stream(fstream)
```

Now we have lots of different options for exporting a `MySpiffy` object by using a `SpiffyFile` object. We can just write it to a file directly:

```
from pathlib import Path
spiff = MySpiffy()
p = Path('spiffies')/'new_spiff.txt'
SpiffyFile(spiff, p).to_file()
```

We can override the path, too:

```
SpiffyFile(spiff).to_file(p.parent/'other_spiff.text')
```

But we can also use an existing open stream:

```
SpiffyFile(spiff).to_stream(my_stream)
```

Or, if we want to edit the string first we could open a new file stream ourselves and write the edited string to it:

```
my_heading = 'This is a spiffy object\n\n'
with open(str(p), mode = 'w') as fout:
    spiff_out = SpiffyFile(spiff).to_str()
    fout.write(my_heading + spiff_out)
```

And finally, we can just use a context manager with the `SpiffyFile` object directly to as many different locations- or streams- as we like (note that we can pass the `pathlib.Path` object directly without worrying about string conversion, which is nifty):

```
with SpiffyFile(spiff, p) as spiff_file:
    spiff_file.to_file()
    spiff_file.to_file(p.parent/'new_spiff.txt')
    print(spiff_file.to_str())
    spiff_file.to_stream(my_open_stream)
```

This approach is more consistent with the mantra: explicit is better than implicit.